# Which of the following is correct: "It cannot be seen, nor touched." and "It cannot be seen, or touched."

Tags: grammar

Helen Keller said, “The best and most
beautiful things in the world cannot be seen, nor touched . . .
but are felt in the heart.”

Shouldn't it be "cannot be seen or touched" since the word "cannot" is used?

Comment: Both are acceptable. _Nor_ is more literary.

Answer (score -2):

In the UK nor is seen as old fashioned in general conversation.

It isn't wrong but it is [affected (meaning 2)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/affected) unless it is in a very old phrase.

I can't speak for other English speaking countries.

Comment: Please add supporting references when making such claims in an answer on ELU (though this question is hardly without duplicates).

Comment: I find "In the UK nor is seen as archaic" hard to believe.  This is why it needs references.

Comment: How can i find a reference of something not being used?

Comment: @WendyG From [Lexico (Oxford)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/nor), I see only the following sense of *nor* being marked as archaic: ‘she thinks she knows better nor me’. Otherwise, it doesn't mention anything about *nor* being an archaic conjunction in UK English. (It mentions another use that is literary, but that doesn't apply to the phrase in the question either.)

Comment: Shoe managed to find two excellent references: Garner in his _Modern American Usage_, and Peters, in _The Cambridge Guide to English Usage_ (at the duplicate). And note how Shoe looks at this particular usage of 'nor', not just the general use of the word. _And_ gives an example where 'nor' **cannot** be replaced by 'or'.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Has Remerkable Affiliations: Peters says that 'nor' is becoming the less common choice in OP's example.